# Room Android :Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor Kotli

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting this error `Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type)` when I implemented ROOM.
And i tried to add an empty constructor but i didn't works. So only I can avoid this problem removing `embedded`, but i would like to find another solution if its possible.

This is my Entity

```
 @Entity(tableName = "events")
class Event(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        var name: String,

        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        var id: String,

        @Embedded
        var images: List<Image>,

        @Embedded
        var dates: Dates,

        @Embedded
        var venues: Venues,
        var favorite: Boolean
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

```
@Entity(tableName = "events")
class Event(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
        @SerializedName("name")
        @Expose
        var name: String,

        @PrimaryKey
        @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
        @SerializedName("id")
        @Expose
        var id: String){

        var images: List<Image>? = null
        var dates: Dates? = null
        var venues: Venues? = null
        var favorite: Boolean = false
}
```

Comment: how does this provide the expected constructor and where did the embedded classes go?

Comment: I have only changed the primary constructor, the other field are still available at the class

Comment: sorry, but I cannot identify any constructor there; only one typo `String){`. ah... now I see what you're trying to do... but theses annotations on the constructor's arguments most likely won't be processed... and `Room` expects an empty constructor.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce try again

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a default constructor, which looks alike this in `Kotlin` (the primary constructor of the class already is the first one line; keyword `constructor` be omitted in most cases; see the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)):

```
@Entity(tableName = "events")
class Event() {
    ...
}
```

or explicitly, without having omitted the `constructor` keyword:

```
@Entity(tableName = "events")
class Event constructor() {

}
```

`var favorite` lacks an annotation and those `@Expose` annotations might be useless. make sure that the embedded classes also feature a primary constructor. when having several constructors in a class, one has to add `@Ignore` annotation to all but one, so that it will know which one to use... and it always has to be an empty constructor, which does not take any argument.